# what is main difference between flexbox and grid in CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, web-frontend

I hope you are doing great. I want to know the main difference between flexbox and grid in CSS and their proper use case.
I would love to hear from you. Your answer is always appreciated.
Thanks,
Khubaib Shoukat.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/quick-whats-the-difference-between-flexbox-and-grid/. Does this helps your problem ?

Comment: If you are going to arrange elements in single dimension either `x` or `y` then go for `flexbox` else `grid`.

Comment: See, I mentioned that I want to know about them as I'm new to the Web. Obviously, It will Help me a lot in the future. @AbinThaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flexbox works for layout in 1 dimension and the grid in 2.